# Downsize image: how to achieve the same quality as browser does, with ImageMagick?

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, scaling

Brief history: last time I was need to shrink quadratic images (e.g. 1080x1080) to size of mobile screen width (e.g. 375x375), for speeding up our internet store on mobile platforms.
Firstly I made resize with standard GD library (we are using PHP), but the quality of resized images was just horrible, as well as file size wasn't reduced much.

So, I decided to resize with Image Magick. Results were better, but not enough.

Images were either too blurry, or vice versa - too sharp. When I was attempting to apply different filters, there was ringing or aliasing or blur or color distortion etc, etc. Anyway, quality loss was noticeable. While any contemporary browser always scales down big picture (1080х1080) with **excellent quality**. How it does it? I don't think they know some secret formulae, this is just technique.
But before I dig into chromium sources, I dare to ask the community.

I tried several approaches:

- Resizing with every existing filter
- Unsharp after resize
- Scale down not to exact size, but to original image width, divided to 2(anyway a browser did the rest of work).

I tried these separately and together.
My attempts are all summarized in this page:

- http://45.135.134.109/gray_woman/375
- http://45.135.134.109/gray_pants/375
- http://45.135.134.109/big_rtrend/375

You can play with settings and estimate the result.
The code is here: https://github.com/alex-rsk/resize_with_im

Any advices would be very appreciated.

Crucial code:

```
`
    $imageBlob = file_get_contents('pics/'.$url.'.jpg');
    $imagick = new Imagick();
    $imagick->readImageBlob($imageBlob);
    if (isset($_GET['krat'])) {
        $imageWidth = $imagick->getImageWidth()/2;       
    } else {
        $imageWidth = $width;
    }
    $gaussRadius = floatval($_GET['gauss_radius'] ?? 0);
    $sigma = floatval($_GET['sigma'] ?? 0.5);
    $threshold = floatval($_GET['threshold'] ?? 0.05);
    $sharp = isset($_GET['sharpen']);
    $quality = intval($_GET['qual'] ?? 100);
    $blur = floatval($_GET['blur'] ?? 1.0);
  
    $filters = [
        'scale'         => 'scale',
        'LANCZOS'       => Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,
        'LANCZOSSHARP'  => Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOSSHARP,
        'ROBIDOUX'      => Imagick::FILTER_ROBIDOUX,
        'ROBIDOUXSHARP' => Imagick::FILTER_ROBIDOUXSHARP,
        'LANCZOS2'      => Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS2,
        'LANCZOS2SHARP' => Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS2SHARP,
        'BOX'           => Imagick::FILTER_BOX,
        'TRIANGLE'      => Imagick::FILTER_TRIANGLE,
        'HERMITE'       => Imagick::FILTER_HERMITE,
        'HANNING'       => Imagick::FILTER_HANNING,
        'HAMMING'       => Imagick::FILTER_HAMMING,
        'BLACKMAN'      => Imagick::FILTER_BLACKMAN,
        'GAUSSIAN'      => Imagick::FILTER_GAUSSIAN,
        'CATROM'        => Imagick::FILTER_CATROM,
        'MITCHELL'      => Imagick::FILTER_MITCHELL,
        'BESSEL'        => Imagick::FILTER_BESSEL,
        'KAISER'        => Imagick::FILTER_KAISER,
        'PARZEN'        => Imagick::FILTER_PARZEN,
        'WELSH'         => Imagick::FILTER_WELSH,
        'SINC'          => Imagick::FILTER_SINC,
    ];
   
    foreach ($filters as $name => $filter) {
        $im = clone $imagick;
        if (isset($_GET['srgb'])) {
             $im->setImageColorspace(\Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);
        }
        $im->setImageCompressionQuality($quality);
        switch ($filter) {
           case 'scale': $im->scaleImage($imageWidth, 0); break;
           default: 
           $im->resizeImage($imageWidth, 0, $filter, $blur); 
        }
        if ($sharp) {
            $im->unsharpMaskImage($gaussRadius, $sigma, 1, $threshold);
        }
         echo '<img style="width:'.$width.'px; height:'.$width.'px" src="data:image/' . $imagick->getImageFormat() . ';base64,' . base64_encode($im->getImageBlob()) . '"/>';
         $im->removeImage();
    }
```

Comment: All relevant code must be included _here_ within your post, not in an external site. Then if any of your links become unavailable in future, readers of the question will still be able to understand it and find it useful. If you don't provide this, the question can be closed as off-topic - see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Updated with code.